# Issues with Image Convolution

Tags: java, image, mask, convolution

I am implementing my own Image Convolution method in Java, it is supposed to be general so I can run any kernals through it. It works and I am able to output things, but the output is wrong. The right side of the image appears on the left hand side, and the image seems to triplicate throughout it with varying intensities. This occurs regardless of the kernal I am running (I have tried 9x9 and standard 3x3) and very similar things occur. I have played with this and changed everything to get it to work but it is still behaving incorrectly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < (image.getWidth()-mask.length); i++)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j < (image.getHeight()-mask.length); j++)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int w = 0; w < mask.length; w++) 
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < mask.length; z++) 
            {
               sum += arr[w + i][z + j] * mask[w][z];   
            }
        }    
        if(sum < 170)
       {
            convArray[i][j] = 0;
       }
        else
       {
            convArray[i][j] = 255;
       }
```

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with this convolution method. What do you do with `convArray` once it has been filled? Are you sure that there is not a problem with the way you display the image?

Comment: This will be terribly slow. Have a look on what I did on C - https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Projects/tree/master/ImageConvolution.